# Is the use of "long since" archaic?

Tags: archaicisms, tone

As a non English speaker, I'm writing a profile in which I want to say something along the lines of: `I've long since developed an interest for...`. In context I feel it flows better than the (more obvious?) `Since a long time, I've developed an interest for..`.

I believe the former is an okay construction, but perhaps a but archaic and/or contrived?

What do you think?

Comment: Being archaic apart, the phrase does not suit the sentence. Please see the meaning and usage in a good dictionary and let us know what you found.

Comment: A quick look at [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+long+since%2Chas+long+since&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20long%20since%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20long%20since%3B%2Cc0) shows that the usage is slowly declining but can hardly be called archaic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulation

> Since a long time

is not correct. We might say

> I have had an interest in XXX **for** a long time

**Since** needs to reference a particular time or date and feels a little better as a qualifier rather than as an initial context. I prefer

> I have been interested in XXX since 1974

to this

> Since 1974 I have been interested in XXX

which feels clumsy.

I would happily use **long since** but then I am pretty archaic myself. In many examples I find it is hyphenated as **long-since**.

Answer (score 4):

The expression "long since" is not archaic, but be careful how you use it. It is an adverbial phrase and as such will normally modify a verb.

Note that your second expression,

> Since a long time, I've developed an interest for . . .

is not something most native speakers would say. That is an artifact of some other languages, notably German.

Comment: In *"We were once close but we've **since** grown apart"* we can use ***long since*** to emphasize how far in the past the transition from *close* to *apart* took place, but using plain ***long*** there doesn't sit well with me. On the other hand, it seems to work fine with *"We were once close but we've **long** been enemies"* (where plain ***since*** doesn't seem quite right to me). Perhaps because ***grow apart*** is a "continuous, ongoing" activity, where ***be enemies*** is a "static state". But is there some reason why ***long since*** seems okay to me in *both* contexts?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've recently become interested in the use of "long since" for reasons apart from this site. Merriam Webster says it means "for a long time", (*the person I knew in the history department has long since been retired*, was how I used it) which is the way I use it. But interestingly neither the OED nor the Shorter OED touch it at all.

Comment: @WS2: I don't think ***for** a long time* is [often?, ever?] a direct replacement for ***long since***. Better would be *a long time **ago***. The point being both ***since*** and ***ago*** both imply two distinct "temporal reference points" (the *later* of which is usually ***now**, time of utterance*, but it could be *[past] narrative **reference** time*). The other "temporal reference point" has to be *earlier* (including ***long*** makes it ***much*** earlier), but it's more about *temporal **distance** [between two reference points]* than ***duration** [of activity]*.

Comment: ...that's to say if someone *has long since been retired*, it's not so much a reference to how long that person has been *in the state of being retired* (a ***duration***) - it's more a reference to how long ***ago*** the "act" of retiring occurred. Admittedly, a small difference in most contexts, but I think sometimes it would be significant.

Comment: @FumbleFingers On reflection, I think I said "(the person) has long since retired" - which fits better with your dictum concerning *temporal distance*, rather than *duration*. Merriam Webster gives two meanings - *long ago* and *for a long time*, which together seem to meet both conditions.

Comment: @WS2: Personally, I don't much like M-W's second example *(has long since been a devoted friend)*. We don't actually have any context for that specific example, obviously, but I'd always be a bit suspicious of any construction where ***has long since been*** is followed by ***a noun*** (as opposed to a "verbed" Past Participle, which we could at least interpret as referring to ***the [past] time of the act of "verbing"***). So far as I'm concerned, things start to fall apart when ***since*** occurs in contexts with no clear reference to some *specific* earlier time (same as ***ago***).

Comment: ...so I'd say this instance of ["halophilic bacteria has long since been a problem"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22bacteria+has+long+since+been+a+problem%22) is effectively a "misuse" of the expression (if you check the surrounding context, I don't think you'll find any clearly-defined "earlier time" that ***since*** could be referencing, which for me at least means it just doesn't work). That problem could be resolved by *...has been a problem **since long ago***, since (!) ***long ago*** does clearly refer to some specific past time, even if it's a bit "vague".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, I think I agree. What I recently wrote to someone (and then wondered afterwards what I had actually said) was *"The only person I ever knew in their history dept has long since retired"*. Did I mean (a) it had been a long time since I knew them, (b) a long time since they retired, or (c) a long time between when I knew them and when they retired? I meant to say (b) and your comments suggest I got it right - thanks!

Comment: @FumbleFingers One reason I find this confusing is that, had I said "the person has since retired" - the past reference point would be when I knew them. But saying "the person has long since retired" seems to shift the reference to the day they retired.

Comment: @WS2: Hmm. My reading of your example is it's meaning **(c).** That's to say, since ***since*** requires a contextually-relevant *point in past time* to be juxtaposed again *time of utterance*, the only credible referent for that "earlier" time has to be ***when I knew them***.

Comment: Ooops - belay that! The "past time" is ***when they retired*** (which is *long **ago*** with reference to time of utterance). But they could have retired immediately after you knew them, or much much later.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am sure your second comment is right. Because had I never said anything about knowing them I could still have said "that person has long since retired". But I could not have said "they have since retired" as there would be no past referent point in time. So what we seem to have established is that "long since" is not simply a more intense form of "since" - but sets its own rules.